# form.fileSelect()の意味がわかりません

Tags: javascript

下記のコードで、 form.fileSelect()はどんな、意味かをどなた様かご教示頂けますでしょうか。
このような関数ないかをしらべたが特になく、自己定義関数にしても、functionがなく、他で使用されている様子もありません。小括弧に中括弧を挟むのも初めて見ました。
そもそも、関数でないとしたら、なにかもわからずに、記法自体調べても検討がつかなかったため、お願い申し上げます。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <form action="Z_confirm.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label for="files" class="fileupImg"><i class="plus icon"></i>ファイルを選択 
  <input type="file" id="files" style="display: none" value="2097152" name="file" multiple />
</label>
    </div>
    <figure>
    <output id="list"></output>
    </figure>
    <div class="fileInfo"></div>

  <button type="button" name="button" id="delete" style="height:20px;">X</button>
<br>
<br>
  <input class="submit step-button" type="submit" value="登録する">
</form>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(function()
      {
          // セットアップ
          var obj = form.fileSelect({
            input : '#files',
            list : '#list',
            deleteBtn : '#delete',
            thumbnail : { width : 150, class : 'thumbnail' },
            //複数のファイルを許可するか？
            multipleFile : true
          });

          // ファイルをセットした時に発火するイベント 引数に選択したファイルが返ってくる
          obj.OnSelectFile(function(file)
          {
            console.log(file);

            //ファイルが存在するか？
            console.log(obj.hasFile());

            //すべてのファイルを取得 配列
            console.log(obj.getFiles());
          });

          //すべてのファイルをリセット
          obj.reset();

      });
    </script>

    <script>
    var form;
    (function(g,$)
    {
      g.fileSelect = function(setting)
      {
        var el = {}, data = {};

        var init = function()
        {
          el.input = $(setting.input);
          el.list = $(setting.list);
          el.deleteBtn = $(setting.deleteBtn);

          data.files = [];

          setUp();
        };

        var setUp = function()
        {
          el.input.on('change', handleFileSelect);
          el.deleteBtn.on('click', deleteFile);
        };

        var hasFile = function() { return data.files.length > 0; }
        var getFiles = function() { return data.files; };

        var handleFileSelect = function(e)
        {
            var file = e.target.files[0],
                reader = new FileReader();

            if(file.type.indexOf("image") < 0) return false;

            reader.onload = (function(file)
            {
              return function(e)
              {
                if(!setting.multipleFile) reset();

                file.src = e.target.result;
                data.files.push(file);
                var spn = $('<span>');
                spn.append($('<img>').attr({
                          src: file.src,
                          width: setting.thumbnail.width,
                          class: setting.thumbnail.class,
                          title: file.name
                      }));

                el.list.append(spn);

                el.input.trigger( "OnSelectFile", file );

                reader.va
              };
            })(file);

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        };

        var deleteVal = function()
        {
          el.input.prop('value','');
        };

        var deleteFile = function()
        {
          el.list.html('');
          data.files = [];
          deleteVal();
        };

        var OnSelectFile = function(fn)
        {
          el.input.on('OnSelectFile', function(e, f){
            fn(f);
          });
        }

        var reset = function(){
          data.files = [];
          el.list.html('');
          deleteVal();
        };

        init();

        return {
          OnSelectFile : OnSelectFile,
          hasFile : hasFile,
          getFiles : getFiles,
          reset : reset
        }
      };
    }(form || (form = {}), jQuery));
    </scrip


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <form action="Z_confirm.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label for="files" class="fileupImg"><i class="plus icon"></i>ファイルを選択 
  <input type="file" id="files" style="display: none" value="2097152" name="file" multiple />
</label>
    </div>
    <figure>
    <output id="list"></output>
    </figure>
    <div class="fileInfo"></div>

  <button type="button" name="button" id="delete" style="height:20px;">X</button>
<br>
<br>
  <input class="submit step-button" type="submit" value="登録する">
</form>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(function()
      {
          // セットアップ
          var obj = form.fileSelect({
            input : '#files',
            list : '#list',
            deleteBtn : '#delete',
            thumbnail : { width : 150, class : 'thumbnail' },
            //複数のファイルを許可するか？
            multipleFile : true
          });

          // ファイルをセットした時に発火するイベント 引数に選択したファイルが返ってくる
          obj.OnSelectFile(function(file)
          {
            console.log(file);

            //ファイルが存在するか？
            console.log(obj.hasFile());

            //すべてのファイルを取得 配列
            console.log(obj.getFiles());
          });

          //すべてのファイルをリセット
          obj.reset();

      });
    </script>

    <script>
    var form;
    (function(g,$)
    {
      g.fileSelect = function(setting)
      {
        var el = {}, data = {};

        var init = function()
        {
          el.input = $(setting.input);
          el.list = $(setting.list);
          el.deleteBtn = $(setting.deleteBtn);

          data.files = [];

          setUp();
        };

        var setUp = function()
        {
          el.input.on('change', handleFileSelect);
          el.deleteBtn.on('click', deleteFile);
        };

        var hasFile = function() { return data.files.length > 0; }
        var getFiles = function() { return data.files; };

        var handleFileSelect = function(e)
        {
            var file = e.target.files[0],
                reader = new FileReader();

            if(file.type.indexOf("image") < 0) return false;

            reader.onload = (function(file)
            {
              return function(e)
              {
                if(!setting.multipleFile) reset();

                file.src = e.target.result;
                data.files.push(file);
                var spn = $('<span>');
                spn.append($('<img>').attr({
                          src: file.src,
                          width: setting.thumbnail.width,
                          class: setting.thumbnail.class,
                          title: file.name
                      }));

                el.list.append(spn);

                el.input.trigger( "OnSelectFile", file );

                reader.va
              };
            })(file);

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        };

        var deleteVal = function()
        {
          el.input.prop('value','');
        };

        var deleteFile = function()
        {
          el.list.html('');
          data.files = [];
          deleteVal();
        };

        var OnSelectFile = function(fn)
        {
          el.input.on('OnSelectFile', function(e, f){
            fn(f);
          });
        }

        var reset = function(){
          data.files = [];
          el.list.html('');
          deleteVal();
        };

        init();

        return {
          OnSelectFile : OnSelectFile,
          hasFile : hasFile,
          getFiles : getFiles,
          reset : reset
        }
      };
    }(form || (form = {}), jQuery));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 質問文を編集してコードを整形してください。また重複したコードが見受けられますが、２重にコピペしていないでしょうか？

Comment: 投稿に含まれるソースコードや、整形済みのテキストは[選択した上で `{}` ボタンをクリック](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/2069/3054)して整形済みブロックにして下さい。インデントが保持され、`<` などの文字もそのまま使えるようになります。

Comment: 自分で書いたコードではないなら、出典の明記と転載の可否の確認をしたほうが良いかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

```
var args = {
  input : '#files',
  list : '#list',
  deleteBtn : '#delete',
  thumbnail : { width : 150, class : 'thumbnail' },
  //複数のファイルを許可するか？
  multipleFile : true
};
var obj = form.fileSelect(args);
```

上記のように書き直すと理解しやすいかと思います。
`form.fileSelect`という関数に、オブジェクトを引数として渡している処理です。
`form.fileSelect`はその次の`<script>`タグで

```
var form;
(function(g,$)
{
  g.fileSelect = function(setting)
  {
    (省略)
  };
}(form || (form = {}), jQuery));
```

と定義されている関数です。

Comment: ご回答有難うございます。なるほど、引数をオブジェクトとすることができるのですぬ。